# Kotlin Library Exported As Jar Usable In Java Code, But Not In Kotlin Code

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I've written a utility library for a project I am working on in Kotlin. The project has a number of dependencies (such as AWS libraries). I want to package the library as a 'fat' .jar so that I can use the library in other projects without issue.

Currently, I am using the gradle shadow plugin. I am able to successfully use the .jar classes in Java code/projects without issue. However, when using the .jar classes in Kotlin projects/code (or attempting to) I am facing visibility issues (code does not compile b/c of unresolved references). I have no idea what I am doing wrong and am not sure if this is a common issue.

I've already tried:

- Gradle Shadow plugin [here](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/getting-started/#default-java-groovy-tasks)
- Modifying the gradle jar task to include all dependencies myself

The fat jar is successfully created in both cases, and usable in Java code, but Kotlin is not able to resolve the references. However, when I create a non fat jar, the classes are visible, but obviously broken (bc of missing dependencies). So, essentially, only when I create a fat .jar, only my Kotlin code cannot use the library.

Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: Does the resulting JAR with Kotlin files also include the `META-INF/*.kotlin_module` files? These are required for the Kotlin compiler to correctly read the declarations. Without them, you might face visibility issues with top-level declarations.

Comment: @hotkey yup, the kotlin_module files are present both in the FAT jar and the original jar

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your re-packaged JAR is missing the `META-INF/*.kotlin_module` files from the original JARs. These are the Kotlin package metadata files which the Kotlin compiler needs to be able to read top-level declarations from the classes.

If these files are lost, you will face visibility issues with top-level declarations and extensions.

You need to configure your fat JAR tools to also copy these files into the resulting JAR.

Comment: The FAT jar contains the META-INF/*.kotlin_module files. So does  the non FAT jar (which is able to be imported and used)

Comment: @plesh Do you relocate any packages for the fat JAR? The `*.kotlin_module` files will point the compiler to the original packages, so if the classes are relocated, it will fail to find them.

Comment: I do not. I was previously, but even without relocating packages I run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to add both the compile time and run time dependencies when you compile your library jar file.

One way to add them would be for example:

```
tasks {
    jar{
        from({
            configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
            configurations.compileClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
        })

        exclude ("META-INF/*.RSA", "META-INF/*.SF", "META-INF/*.DSA")
    }
}
```